# Looping until a certain character is inputted?

Tags: java, loops

I took an excerpt of my code that needs working on, I know its standard practice to post all of the code but I dont think its needed here.

```
    if(playerValue > 10 && playerValue < 21){

            System.out.println("Players Value so far " + playerValue + ", Do you want to draw another card? Y/N");
            //  input a y or n answer
            decision = sob.next();

            if(decision.equals("Y") || decision.equals("y")){
                continue;

            }else if(decision.equals("N") || decision.equals("n")){
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

How how I change this statement to either accept a Y or N, as right now if I input anything bar them two character, it will continue as if I have pressed Y.

Comment: why cant you use do - while loop in Java?

Comment: You should have an else case...

Comment: I've thought of that but been confused with how I would do it. @hagubear

Comment: Also instead of doing equals("y") twice you could use equalsIgnoreCase once for y and n...

Answer (score 1):

You should have an else case:

```
if(playerValue > 10 && playerValue < 21){

            System.out.println("Players Value so far " + playerValue + ", Do you want to draw another card? Y/N");
            //  input a y or n answer
            decision = sob.next();

            if(decision.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
                continue;

            }else if(decision.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                 //whatever you want to happen if they don't enter either y or n
            }

        }
    }
```

Maybe in the else have another loop that says please enter a valid input and keep looping until they give a valid input...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can change your code to "insist" on the user to enter a `Y` or a `N`:

```
static void readYesOrNo(Scanner input) {
    String str;
    while (true) {
        str = input.next();
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            return true;
        }
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter Y or N");
    }
}
```

I put this code into a static method so that you could reuse it in other places. Now you can use this method in your code like this:

```
if(playerValue > 10 && playerValue < 21){
    System.out.println("Players Value so far " + playerValue + ", Do you want to draw another card? Y/N");
    if (readYesOrNo(sob)) {
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This:

```
        if(playerValue > 10 && playerValue < 21){
          while(true){
          System.out.println("Players Value so far " + playerValue + ", Do you want to draw another card? Y/N");
          //  input a y or n answer

         decision=sob.next();
         if(decision!=null && (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("y")||decision.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))){
            break;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("please answer with Either y or n");
            continue;
          }
        }//end of while loop

        //put your code here 
     }
```